# Issue with Maven: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Tags: maven

I am very new to Maven. I am facing an issue while installation of Maven into Eclipse. How can I resolve this?

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.0.20130601-0317/plugins/org.
>   eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.4.0.20130531-2315.jar.
>       Read timed out

Comment: maybe you need to specify maven proxy settings

Comment: sorry I meant eclipse proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

The linke http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.0.20130601-0317/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.4.0.20130531-2315.jar is accessible.  It must have been an intermittent network error, at your end or on the server side.